# Doesn´t recognice as equal (==)

Tags: google-apps-script

Can someone tell me why these variables marked with red are not recognized as equal (`==`).

[image]

Comment: What is this supposed to be?

Comment: Side note: I recommend using `===` and `!==` instead of `==` and `!=`. See the discussions here: [Which equals operator (== vs ===) should be used in JavaScript comparisons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/which-equals-operator-vs-should-be-used-in-javascript-comparisons)

Answer (score 0):

Google Apps Script is Javascript-based. In Javascript, you can not compare two arrays using `==`.

One method is to loop over both arrays and to check that the values are the same. For example you can include the function:

```js
function compareArrays(array1, array2) {
        for (var i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
                if (array1[i] instanceof Array) {
                        if (!(array2[i] instanceof Array) || compareArrays(array1[i], array2[i]) == false) {
                                return false;
                        }
                }
                else if (array2[i] != array1[i]) {
                        return false;
                }
        }
        return true;
}
```

And then update the line in your code from `if (responsables == gestPor) {` to `if (compareArrays(responsables, gestPor)) {`

For other methods of comparing arrays in Javascript, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14853974).

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are comparing arrays. If you are just getting a single cell value, use `getValue()` instead of `getValues()`

To make things work, change these:

```
var gestPor = hojaActivador.getRange(i,13,1,1).getValues();
var responsables = hojaConMails.getRange(1,n,1,1).getValues();
```

to:

```
var gestPor = hojaActivador.getRange(i,13).getValue();
var responsables = hojaConMails.getRange(1,n).getValue();
```

Do these to all `getValues()` where you're only extracting 1 cell/value.

See difference below:
[image: difference]